# How can I write in a way that makes the book very interesting to read?

Tags: creative-writing

This is a really weird question, but, for me this matters because English is not my first language.

Whenever I read these famous novels, the authors use words which have really deep meanings and which makes the book very interesting to read. So my question is: how do I write that way?

I really want to improve my writing as well as my English.

And also I am writing a book and I want to make it as good as I can, I would love to get some tips regarding that.

Comment: Small FYI: if you want to do a paragraph break in your text, you need to do 'enter' twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some great tips here already. I'll add one more that you could try:

Team up with an English writer. If you can find one who is trying to learn to write in your native tongue, even better! You can help each other. Correcting people's writing and vocabulary is usually seen as impolite. And often, as long as your meaning is understood, people won't say anything about how it's written or worded.

What will help you develop your English language is having someone who can critique your work. If you aren't made aware of the mistakes you may be making with your writing, how will you ever improve?

Reading, yes. But reading can be a very passive way of learning, particularly if you're reading at night, ready for sleep. Writing is a much more active way of learning but you need someone to correct it for you. You learn quickly from mistakes.

I did Arabic classes when I lived in the middle east and having a native speaker read my work really helped.

But try to find a creative writer, someone who knows the craft well, not a member of your family or a good friend who may be too careful of your feelings to give you brutally open and honest feedback on your work. I also find that readers who have no training or experience in the craft, often know something isn't quite right, but can't always articulate why it's not working the way it should.

Good luck!

Comment: @yassmeen I had another thought too, I listen to a lot of audiobooks. Audiobooks allow you to be reading while you're driving, doing house work, walking the dog, shopping, etc. Instead of having to find the time to sit down and read, you can be 'reading' constantly. Whenever I'm not writing, I have an audiobook playing in my ear. Either a novel in my writing genre or a how-to book on writing. It means I'm constantly studying the craft. Listening to English books in your genre could really help you find your own voice in English, I'd highly recommend it. And glad the answer was helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Vocabulary alone isn't enough to make your book interesting. In fact, if your story is too heavy with obscure words, it might become hard to read and off-putting.

That said, growing your vocabulary is a good idea for a writer: your vocabulary is your arsenal of tools that you can use as you see fit. It's always a good idea to have more tools at your hand.

So how do you grow your vocabulary? You **read**. A lot. You familiarise yourself with the use of the words you like. Once a word is firmly in your passive vocabulary (that is, you've seen it in writing in multiple contexts), it passes naturally into your active vocabulary: when you need that particular word, it will come to you naturally. It's the same as learning a language: reading in a foreign language helps you accustom your mind to what words exist and how they're employed.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's to keep the reader guessing where you are taking them. Writing well gramatically with rich vocabulary, is the art of the execution only. Complex fictional characters and story-lines often based loosely on real-life people and events in the past (sometimes autobiographical), can encourage a reader to come along with you for the ride as they twist and lurch with you around those sinuous bends. A good story for me is unpredictable. You can also use a dark ironic humour like Sylvia Plath did in her book "The Bell Jar" if you are that type of person.GoodLuck.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Nice answer. If you have spare time, you may want to check out the [help] and the [tour]. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the given answers,

Firstly, developing your vocabulary is a good idea. A writer, according to me, should have a good grip on vocabulary.

Some tips to improve vocabulary -

- **Read**. Read a lot. Read as much as you can. Read newspaper, read articles, read novels.
- **Write as much as you can.** This doesn't require your writing to be top notch. Just write. Write in different sites, discussion forums, maybe create your small personal blog.
- There are many **mobile applications** that help you build your vocabulary on a daily basis. This might be helpful if you don't have an access to any above points at any time.
- There is this one book - **Wordpower made easy by Norman Lewis**. This is one the most famous book for improving vocabulary. *(I have also used this)*

Now talking about the intriguing part, to keep the reader interested, keep the following points in mind -

- Make a **detailed structure of your characters**. It is said that you should be knowing your characters so well, as if their some alive people in your life.
- Whenever you're writing a scene, **describe the scene**. Give a detailed, *yet brief,* description of the scene. Write about the view, the atmosphere, the weather.. But keep in mind, don't write too much about it. The reader is being introduced to the scene so don't drag it too much.
- Lastly, write about the **emotions of the characters in the scene.** Say you're writing a battle scene, then you write about the emotions of the warriors - like all were furious, angry on their enemies, bravery spread in the air, etc.

Hope this helps you. Good luck!